# Simple reduced rings which are not domains

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

a ring $R$ is reduced if for each $a\in R$ , $a^n=0$ implies that $a=0$ for any positive integer $n$. also $R$ is called simple if it doesn't have any proper two-sided ideal.

Is there any example of a ring $R$ which is both simple and reduced and also not a domain?

Comment: Take any field!

Comment: sorry I forgot to add  the nondomain properties

Comment: See [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~lwsmall/MATH207A/ringtheorynotes.pdf), Theorem $6.17$ by Andrunakievič.

Comment: tnx. i fixed it

Comment: @Cary thanks! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Such rings do not exist. It was proved in 1968:
Andrunakievič, V. A.; Rjabuhin, Ju. M.
Rings without nilpotent elements, and completely prime ideals.
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 180 1968 9–11.

From MathSci review;

...From here, it follows that a ring has no non-zero nilpotent elements if and only if it is isomorphic to a subdirect product of (non-commutative) integral domains.
{This article has appeared in English translation [Soviet Math. Dokl. 9 (1968), 565–568].}
Reviewed by V. Dlab